# Does z3 have equivalent operator functions?

Tags: z3py

Here's a simplified example of what I am trying to do

```
import sys
current_module = sys.modules['z3']
stringOp = 'add' #user input
z3_exp1 = getattr(current_module, stringOp)(x, 2)
print(z3_exp1) #expect something like x + 2
```

The operator/function will be supplied by the user as a string, this works with 'Implies' since that is a function in z3. I know python has equivalent functions like a + b is equivalent to add(a, b). I looked but I can't find something similar in z3. If not, any other ideas on how I can do this?

I want to be able to do this with every function z3 offers, so if statements don't seem the right choice to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the overladed functions:

```py
from z3 import *

expr = None
x = Int('x')

stringOp = "add"

if stringOp == "add":
    expr = (x).__add__(2)
elif stringOp == "sub":
    expr = (x).__sub__(2)
else:
    raise Exception("I don't know how to handle: " + stringOp)

print(expr)
```

This prints:

```
x + 2
```

Comment: But I want to be able to do this with every function z3 has, the if statements will be too much no? (i.e. I want to handle every function z3 can handle and I don't know what the user may input)

Comment: I don't think you can do any better. You seem to be trying to solve the "parsing" problem "magically." Unless you resort to `eval` like tricks, you have to pay the cost of parsing/analyzing; or you need to use some other library that does the same.